# Azure Search filter for "like" or "contains"

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-cognitive-search

What is the correct filter syntax for doing a like or contains?

I would like to pull all fileNames that contain "test" in the file name.

I've tried this in the search explorer, but it didn't work

```
$filter=search.in(fileName, 'test')
```

or

```
$filter=search.ismatch('test')
```

I also need to do this via the C# Azure Search:

```
            SearchOptions options = new SearchOptions()
            {
                Filter = string.Format("{0} ne '{1}'", FileManagerMetadataContants.IsFileDeleted, FileManagerMetadataContants.IsFileDeletedValue),
                SearchMode = SearchMode.Any,
                IncludeTotalCount = true,
            };
```

[image]

[image]

Here are the versions I'm on:

```
  <package id="Azure.Search.Documents" version="11.1.1" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Azure.Storage.Blobs" version="12.4.4" targetFramework="net461" />
```

Comment: Is there a reason you want to use filters instead of using the search parameter? You can do search scoped to fields and use regex, prefix/sufix/infix search
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/query-lucene-syntax

Comment: @ramero-MSFT: I can use whatever is supported, but I'm having a hard time finding what that is. If my index filed is "fileName" and that "fileName" is "test_file.xlsx", I need to be able to search a fileName with just "test" and have it return. We are not storing the actually file name in the blob name because we need it to be unique. What would be the regex for contains?

Answer (score 1):

Please try something like this:

```
$filter=search.ismatch('*test*', 'fileName', 'full', 'any')
```

Refer [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-query-odata-full-text-search-functions).

Comment: This helped me out, thank you. The syntax is incorrect though - you don't need the '*'s. It should be like this: ```$filter=search.ismatch('test', 'fileName', 'full', 'any')```